# Snowflake how to parse any date or date-time values into YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I am working with Snowflake into getting data from various data sources where date and date-time formats are not the same even within some systems.

We might have:

`2021-11-04T00:00:00.000+06:00`

or

`2021-11-04`

or even:

`04/11/2021`

I tried to use the following:

```
SELECT ifnull(try_to_date('2021-11-04T00:00:00.000+06:00'), to_date('2021-11-04T00:00:00.000+06:00'))
```

But it doesn't work when the date is like `04/11/2021`

I don't want to make the query bigger as it is within a huge ingest script and 1ms counts for us.

Is there way to parse any type of date and date-time into `YYYY-MM-DD` for a reason that's related to our warehouse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different formats with a `COALESCE`, then the first non-null parsed will output the date:

```sql
select coalesce(
  try_to_date(mydate)
  , try_to_date(mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  , try_to_date(mydate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) as parsed_dae
```

Other specifiers supported:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#about-the-format-specifiers-in-this-section